# MaskedEditText hint(android)

Tags: android, xml

I am using the [maskedEditText](https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText) library. Everything is working fine, but if I set `hint` it doesn't work. Example: I have this xml:

```
 <br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText 
                        android:id="@+id/phoneSend"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="(111) 111 11 11"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        mask:mask="(###) ###-##-##"
                    >
                    </br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText>
```

If I want to enter text: `12345`

It displays: `23451`

If I delete  `android:hint="(111) 111 11 11"` everything works fine. But I need to use hint

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your MaskedEditText template TextInputLayout and it is in it that you type a hint:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilPhoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Input phone (111) 111-11-11">

        <br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText
            android:id="@+id/metPhone"
            style="@style/..."
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            app:allowed_chars="1234567890"
            app:keep_hint="true"
            app:mask="(###) ###-##-##"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```